# When adding a Menu to a Window using a Grid, do I give the Menu its own row or do I use some kind of panel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to understand how to add a `Menu` to my WPF XAML window. My window currently uses a `Grid` for content layout. I'd like to add a `Menu` at the top of the window, similar to how you usually see in WinForm applications.

I've looked around at examples, but none of the examples seem to explain the use a `Grid`. I see most examples using things like a `StackPanel`, or `DockPanel`.

Here's my current `Window`, with the `Grid`. Should I just give this `Menu` its own row, or do I need some sort of panel?

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="File" />
        </Menu>
        <GroupBox Header="Seasons" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <DataGrid Name="lstSeasons" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" ItemsSource="{Binding SeasonsCollectionView}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Division" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Division}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `Menu` to the main WPF layout `Grid` as shown in the following example:

```
<Menu Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0">
    <MenuItem Header="_File"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Edit"/>
    <MenuItem Header="_Help"/>
</Menu>
```

You do not need any other container controls in order to complete this task. The screenshot of the actual WPF app using this `Menu` technique is shown here (notice the `Menu` Bar at the top of the app window): http://examn8.com

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pretty common implementation I see that seems to work pretty well:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Menu Grid.Row="0">
        <MenuItem Header="Load" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Save" IsEnabled="True"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Import/Export" IsEnabled="False">
            <MenuItem Header="_Import"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Export"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <TreeView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="tests" Width="auto">
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

If there are multiple columns, you should set the Grid.ColumnSpan attribute on the Menu.